# Passing React Component to Another Component?

Tags: reason, reason-react

I'm trying to define a `ProductRow` and `ProductCategoryRow` from [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

**productRow.re**

```jsx
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("ProductRow");

let make = (~name, ~price, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) => {
    <tr>
      <td>{ReasonReact.stringToElement(name)}</td>
      <td>{ReasonReact.stringToElement(price)}</td>
    </tr>
  }
};
```

**productCategoryRow.re**

```jsx
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("ProductCategoryRow");

let make = (~title: string, ~productRows, _children) => {
  ...component,
  render: (_self) => {
    <div>
        <th>{ReasonReact.stringToElement(title)}</th>
    </div>
  }
};
```

I believe that I need to `map` over the `productRows`, i.e. `List of ProductRow`'s, with a function of: `productRow => <td>productRow</td>`.

How can I do that in this example?

Or, if I'm completely off the mark, please explain how I can achieve the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 'Thinking in React' page, the component nesting hierarchy is such that a `ProductTable` contains several `ProductRow`s. We can model that in ReasonReact by mapping over an array of products and producing `ProductRow`s as the output. E.g.:

```jsx
type product = {name: string, price: float};

/* Purely for convenience */
let echo = ReasonReact.stringToElement;

module ProductRow = {
  let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("ProductRow");
  let make(~name, ~price, _) = {
    ...component,
    render: (_) => <tr>
      <td>{echo(name)}</td>
      <td>{price |> string_of_float |> echo}</td>
    </tr>
  };
};

module ProductTable = {
  let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("ProductTable");
  let make(~products, _) = {
    ...component,
    render: (_) => {
      let productRows = products
        /* Create a <ProductRow> from each input product in the array. */
        |> Array.map(({name, price}) => <ProductRow key=name name price />)
        /* Convert an array of elements into an element. */
        |> ReasonReact.arrayToElement;

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr> <th>{echo("Name")}</th> <th>{echo("Price")}</th> </tr>
        </thead>
        /* JSX can happily accept an element created from an array */
        <tbody>productRows</tbody>
      </table>
    }
  };
};

/* The input products. */
let products = [|
  {name: "Football", price: 49.99},
  {name: "Baseball", price: 9.99},
  {name: "Basketball", price: 29.99}
|];

ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<ProductTable products />, "index");
```

Comment: Thanks, Yawar! Is the choice of 'name' as the key a good idea since names could have duplicates, as I understand?

Comment: @KevinMeredith that's a good point, ideally each product in stock should have a SKU which should serve as a unique key.

Comment: I'm seeing `Unbound record field name` in the lambda of `Array.map`. Any idea, why, please?

Comment: @KevinMeredith usually this means your record is defined in a different module than where you're using it. You can tell Reason where by prefixing one of the fields with the module name, e.g. `Array.map(({MyModule.name, price}) => ...)`

Comment: In order to use `MyModule.name`, must I define a `module` as you have?
 Or is it sufficient to create `MyModule.re`, which contains both a `component` and `make` `let`'s?

Comment: @KevinMeredith if you're seeing an `unbound record field` error, that means you either haven't defined the record type, or have defined it in another module. So you would prefix one of the fields with that module name in the latter case. Anyway you can get more help in the Discord (I'm temporarily locked out but there are a lot of folks who can help).

Comment: I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48779363/unbound-record-field-name-in-reason-component. Thanks for your help!