# Unbound record field name in Reason Component

Tags: reason, reason-react

Borrowing just about all of Yawar's helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48514159/409976), I have the following:

```
$cat src/index.re 
let products = [|
  {name: "Football", price: 49.99},
  {name: "Basebll", price: 1.99},
  {name: "Poker", price: 33.99}
|];

ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(
    <ProductTable products />
);

$cat src/productRow.re
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("ProductRow");

let echo = ReasonReact.stringToElement;

let make = (~name: string, ~price: float, _) => {
 ...component,
 render: (_) => {
    <tr>
     <td>{echo(name)}</td>
     <td>{price |> string_of_float |> echo}</td>
    </tr>
 }
};
$cat src/ProductTable.re
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("ProductTable");

let echo = ReasonReact.stringToElement;

let make = (~products, _) => {
    ...component,
    render: (_) => {
      let productRows = products
        |> Array.map(({name, price}) => <ProductRow key=name name price />)
        |> ReasonReact.arrayToElement;

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>{echo("Name")}</th>
            <th>{echo("Price")}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>productRows</tbody>
      </table>
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following compile-time error:

```
   7 ┆ render: (_) => {
   8 ┆   let productRows = products
   9 ┆     |> Array.map(({name, price}) => <ProductRow key=name name price />
       )
  10 ┆     |> ReasonReact.arrayToElement;
  11 ┆ 

  Unbound record field name
```

How can I fix this compile-time error?

Answer (score 4):

The Reason compiler will infer a lot of types for you but for records, you have to first declare what fields it has (and their types) ahead of time.

Pulling from @yawar's helpful answer, you simply need to include the type definition at the top of your file:

`type product = {name: string, price: float};`

With that, the compiler will be able to tell that `products` is of type `array(product)` and should continue along happily from there. Give it a try [here](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html?rrjsx=true&reason=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-KWv+wDfBsFogaBsCkry3yisWNwAHK+C8ZpgbBGFQGKJo3I0ORoUKcrwURfJzta4EkJBUG8qYSAgKSk4Xso1p0YgDECtagHEn+UBFIQdoOkmwAACIAPIALLrL6zIZO68AAKIyBQKwAOoMGBACSiBXNy57AHmQxMUoUDPjYehwBAABuDAQE8rx4EAA)